# How to simply filter a Collection(View)(DataGrid) through a ComboBox via Item Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, filter, collectionviewsource

after searching for hours and hours over weeks (at SO and google, I even asked ChatGPT), I was not able to find a Solution for my (simple?) Problem, although I have become close to my desired result.

**What I have:**
I have an c# wpf xaml application, where I display some datagrids (as CollectionViewSource), any of them are filled by `List<MyModel>`, where each Model Containing different strings as propertys.
I already use them as CollectionView in the XAML, have an filter in code behind, and can display the Lists.

**XAML:**

```
<Page.Resources>
     <CollectionViewSource Filter="MyFilter" Source="{Binding Aktie.AktieBuchwerte}" x:Key="AktieBuchwerte" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView">
         <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
             <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Datum" Direction="Descending"/>
     </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</Page.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Aktie.AktieBuchwerte}"
          Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftMargin}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Quelle"
          SelectedValuePath="Quelle"
          x:Name="BuchWertComboBox"
          SelectedValue="Marketscreener"/>

<DataGrid
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          GridLinesVisibility="All"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AktieBuchwerte}}"
          KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once">
          <DataGrid.Resources>
              <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray" />
              </Style>
          </DataGrid.Resources>
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Datum, StringFormat=yyyy}" Header="Jahr" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value, ConverterCulture=de-de}" Header="Buchwert" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Schätzung, ConverterCulture=de-de}" Header="Schätzung" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quelle, ConverterCulture=de-de}" Header="Quelle" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class DataGridDetailPage : Page
{
    
    public DataGridDetailPage(DataGridDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
 
    private void MyFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is AktieBuchwert obj)
        {
            e.Accepted = obj.Quelle == (string)BuchWertComboBox.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class DataGridDetailViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly ISQLiteDataService _SQLiteDataService;
    private Aktie _aktie;

    public Aktie Aktie
    {
        get { return _aktie; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _aktie, value); }
    }

    public DataGridDetailViewModel(ISQLiteDataService SQLiteDataService)
    {
        _SQLiteDataService = SQLiteDataService;

    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is int Id)
        {
            Aktie = await _SQLiteDataService.GetGridDetailDataAsync(Id);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Aktie
{
    public List<AktieBuchwert> AktieBuchwerte { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class AktieBuchwert : AktieKennzahlen
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public bool Schätzung { get; set; }

        public string Quelle { get; set; }
    }
```

[Actual result ComboBox & List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80zd1.png)
[Actual result ComboBox dropdown & List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd10C.png)

**What I am not able to / where I could need some help after endless researching on my own:**
I am not able to:

**A:** get rid of the multiple lines showing in the combobox dropdown. Basically there are two values in this case: string Value A (Boerse.de) or string Value B (Marketscreener), I want the ComboBox only to show the single values that are available in the PropertyField "Quelle" in the underlying List, not to show each property value of each Object (normal filter behaviour I would asume?)

**B:** get the List filtered dynamically. I only see items in the List, if I hardcode the "Marketscreener" or "Boerse.de" into the "SelectedValue" of the ComboBox. Good is, that I see the corresponding correct items (only with Marketscreener if selected e.g.), but as soon as I try so attach Binding to that Selected Value Field, my List is empty, e.g:
`SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource AktieBuchwerte}, Path=Quelle}"` is giving me following result:
[Dynamic selected value:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjztl.png)

I have tried many different combinations, and even that i have a filter now was hours and hours of research. I can not believe, that something so trivial like filtering a list is not possibile within some small amount of line of codes?

Would be glad if someone have the right answer to this...
Best regards
P.S.: For those of you, who are curious about ChatGPTs answer, here it is:
[ChatGPTs answer on my Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv3m1.png)

Comment: See the [following](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53914.wpfentity-framework-core-primer-c.aspx#DataGrid_Filtering) which works with a TextBox, perhaps it can be modified for your task.

Comment: Hi, why are you using the CollectionViewSource at all instead of binding to a list?

Comment: Hi @horotab , I dont know, from my research and testing I understood, that in the end it is always a CollectionViewSource and this is the only way wpf/xaml internally can filter, sort etc. If there is an easy way with List, I will go for it, my Collection in my App is anyway a list and the binding to the viewsource is to this list (<CollectionViewSource Filter="MyFilter" Source="{Binding Aktie.AktieBuchwerte}" <- this Binding is a list)

Comment: Can you add some code of you DataContext? like how the Aktie property looks and how its loaded?

Comment: @horotab I have added some more context for better understanding (of course e.g. Aktie has a lot more properties, but for this specific grid/list only the one list shown above is important)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a additional list properties to do stuff like this.
This solution is not perfect but easy and effective.
Also it allows you to add more filter logic if required.

**ViewModel (DataGridDetailViewModel):**

```
public async void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is int id)
        await Initialize(id);
}

private async Task Initialize(int id)
{
    Aktie = await _SQLiteDataService.GetGridDetailDataAsync(id);
    var quellen = Aktie.AktieBuchwerte.GroupBy(buchwert => buchwert.Quelle).Select(group => group.Key).ToList();
    quellen.ForEach(quelle => Quellen.Add(quelle));
    SelectedQuelle = quellen.FirstOrDefault();
}

public ObservableCollection<string> Quellen { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public List<Buchwert> FilteredBuchwerte => GetFilteredBuchwerte();

public string SelectedQuelle
{
    get => _selectedQuelle;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _selectedQuelle))
            return;
        _selectedQuelle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedQuelle));
        // make the UI fetch the filtered list again
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredBuchwerte));
    }
}

public Aktie Aktie
{
    get => _aktie;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _aktie))
            return;
        _aktie = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Aktie));
        // make the UI fetch the filtered list again
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredBuchwerte));
    }
}

private List<Buchwert> GetFilteredBuchwerte()
{
    if (Aktie?.AktieBuchwerte == null)
        return new List<Buchwert>();
    IEnumerable<Buchwert> buchwerte = Aktie.AktieBuchwerte.ToList();
    buchwerte = buchwerte.Where(buchwert => buchwert.Quelle == SelectedQuelle);
    buchwerte = buchwerte.OrderByDescending(buchwert => buchwert.Datum);
    return buchwerte.ToList();
}
```

The setter could also be something like:

```
set
{
    SetProperty(ref _selectedQuelle , value);
    // make the UI fetch the filtered list again
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredBuchwerte));
}
```

just make shure the UI is notified that the filtered list is changed as well.

**View:**
You won't need the `<Page.Resources>` block then, the `MyFilter()` in code behind will also no longer be required.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Quellen}"
          Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftMargin}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedQuelle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          GridLinesVisibility="All"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredBuchwerte}">
[...]
</DataGrid>
```

**Edit:**
Added null check to GetFilteredBuchwerte().

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your time and effort!! It works, it's getting the job done, the result is, what I wanted. ComboBox is showing the 2 possible values, selecting is filtering the list (I didnt need the Aktie part, btw) :) 
BUT: I still wonder, where the problem is with the solution via xaml with almost no code behind. My code above is so near to the solution, that I assume, there are only some minor changes necessary to also work...
this BUT is not against your solution, I will use it (because I have no choice and no more time to waste) Thank you again for saving my time :)

Comment: @Qm666 You have one entry in the combobox per item in the list, you would need to add something to filter / group that (**A**). `SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource AktieBuchwerte}, Path=Quelle}"` (**B**) This does not make sense at all. AktieBuchwerte is some list-like structure. The list has maybe some Properties like Length/Count, but Quelle is the name of the property of every single item in the list. I don't know how your code could be made to work, but maybe binding so some kind of CollectionViewSource.FilterDescriptions and there filtering for the quelle could be it.